# Dual Monitor - gdm3 uses wrong monitor

Tags: linux, debian, display, multi-monitor, gdm

I have a dual monitor setup for Debian and my Desktop Environment is `GNOME`. I set the primary screen to screen 1 in `Settings > Displays` and it works fine. But my Display Manager `gdm3` does not respect GNOME's settings. It started outputting the login prompt to screen 2 instead. How do I edit gdm3 configuration so that gdm3 also considers screen 1 as the default?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has actively been ignored by gdm since before 2020.

What I did was to override gdm3 config as explained in this workaround. Its from a related gdm3 script project, but it gives a workaround for gdm3 itself. I personally use Single display config and it works for me, you might need to Mirror if SD does not work.

[Add support to multi-screen](https://github.com/thiggy01/change-gdm-background/issues/15)